# A probable misdescription of official Doc about $MachinePrecision?

Tags: numerics, precision-and-accuracy

According to the [official documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Numbers.html#21155):

> When you enter an approximate real number, the Wolfram Language has to decide whether to treat it as a machine number or an arbitrary‐precision number. Unless you specify otherwise, if you give less than `$MachinePrecision` digits, the Wolfram Language will treat the number as machine precision, and if you give more digits, it will treat the number as arbitrary precision.

However the code below disagree:

```
In[237]:= $MachinePrecision
Precision[0.1000000000000000](*16 digits*)
Precision[0.10000000000000000] (*17 digits*)
Precision[0.100000000000000000](*18 digits*)

Out[237]= 15.9546

Out[238]= MachinePrecision

Out[239]= MachinePrecision

Out[240]= 17.
```

It's only up to 18 digits that it is recognized as an arbitrary precision number.
Is the documentation wrong?

Also, why `Precision[0.100000000000000000](*18 digits*)` output 17? I think it should be 18.

---

### update 2020-06-07

I sent an email and has received the reply from Wolfram Official. It has been confirmed this is an documentation mistake:

> Hello,
>
> Thank you for contacting Wolfram Technical Support. I understand that
> the statement about precision in the following tutorial:
>
> https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/InputSyntax.html#19291
>
> contradicts the statement about precision in the Numerical Precision
> section of the following tutorial:
>
> https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Numbers
>
> I will file a report with our developers regarding this issue. Thank
> you for bring this to our attention.
>
> Regards,
>
> Luke Titus Wolfram Technical Support Wolfram Research Inc.
> http://support.wolfram.com

Comment: But notice that the precision of your 18-digit number is only 17, as you show, and indeed this is the first one that is treated as arbitrary precision because it is the first to have more than `$MachinePrecision` digits of precision. So the documentation is accurate there. Why, then, the number with 18 apparent decimal digits only properly has 17 digits of precision is your real question, and I suspect that this has to do with number representation, something I wish I had a better grasp of.

Comment: @MarcoB  About "So the documentation is accurate there". Documentation said "give less than \$MachinePrecision digits" not "give a number with precision less than \$MachinePrecision", so it's inaccurate.

Comment: Consider `Accuracy[0.100000000000000000]` (18 digits). Note "treat the number as arbitrary precision" makes no promise about the `Precision` of the number.

Comment: @Murphy What are you looking for here? If your only intent is to point out an imprecision in the docs, then you need to contact Wolfram Support. Otherwise, I think you will be interested in the specific definitions of Precision and Accuracy, as reported in the respective documentation pages. I find those concepts pretty hard to keep straight myself, but I think you might be switching up Accuracy and Precision.

Comment: @MarcoB My intent is to point out an imprecision in the docs and, what's more important, find the precise rule behind Mathematica.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The input syntax of numbers is described in more detail in
[Input Syntax](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/InputSyntax.html#19291):

> An approximate number `x` is taken to be machine precision if the number of digits given in it is `Ceiling[$MachinePrecision]+1` or less. If more digits are given, then x is taken to be an arbitrary‐precision number. The accuracy of `x` is taken to be the number of digits that appear to the right of the decimal point, while its precision is taken to be `Log[10,Abs[x]]+Accuracy[x]`.

For a possible explanation why `Ceiling[$MachinePrecision]+1` is chosen, see the SO Q&A [Why do I need 17 significant digits (and not 16) to represent a double?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118231/why-do-i-need-17-significant-digits-and-not-16-to-represent-a-double/)

If `Accuracy[0.100000000000000000]` is `18.`, then `Precision[0.100000000000000000]` should be `Accuracy[0.100000000000000000] + Log10[0.100000000000000000]`, which is `17.`

I think that explains everything.

Frankly, one ought to avoid relying on the "convenience" of writing a long sequence of digits to set a precision/accuracy to what you want.  Use the back-tick input form, `SetPrecision` or `SetAccuracy` instead.  Sometimes the convenience might outweigh the potential for mistakes. The number might come from an external data source in such a form, for instance, but one should probably check and set the accuracy by hand since the rule above might not be how the accuracy of the data should be treated.

Comment: So it's indeed a wrong description, thought it's correctly stated somewhere else. It seems there are quite a few mistakes in the official documentation. I just submitted a Documentation Feedback, which I do in order to find out whether they treat their documentation website seriously.